# How do I configure Glassfish 4 cluster for sticky sessions?

Tags: apache, jakarta-ee, configuration, ssh, glassfish

Trying to set up (in a test environment) a two-server Glassfish 4 cluster in readiness from migrating from our existing single-instance Glassfish 3.1 webserver to one that supported load balancing and failover.

Primarily an application writer, the noddy-GUI interface of Glassfish looked enticing to me. In practice I have been unable to get a Glassfish 4 cluster working correct and wondered if someone could give me the configuration that I needed. There are many blogs and guides describing the process, but they are all slightly different, for different versions of Glassfish, and none of them appear to work on GF4.

The setup:

Server 1: app01
To house DAS, and NODE01->INSTANCE0101(SSH)

Server 2: app02
To house NODE02-INSTANCE0102(SSH)

Cluster: CLUSTER01, involving NODE01->INSTANCE0101 and NODE02->INSTANCE0102

Having set up the two servers, java, and installed Glassfish 4 on app01. Have installed Apache on app01.
Our old server used Apache and mod_jk to forward appropriate requests to Glassfish. I had made the appropriate change in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf to forward requests to jk-connector: (pulled from appropriate sections)

```
    LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so
    JkWorkersFile /etc/httpd/conf/workers.properties
    JkLogFile /var/log/httpd/mod_jk.log
    JkLogLevel error
    JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] "
    JkOptions +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURICompat -ForwardDirectories

    JkMount /* loadbalancer
```

This is what I thought was appropriate for workers.properties from all of the blog posts.

```
    worker.list=loadbalancer

    # default properties for workers
    worker.template.type=ajp13
    worker.template.lbfactor=50
    worker.template.connection_pool_timeout=600
    worker.template.socket_keepalive=1
    worker.template.socket_timeout=300

    # properties for worker1
    worker.worker1.reference=worker.template
    worker.worker1.host=app01.btodomain.bto.org
    worker.worker1.port=8009

    # properties for worker2
    worker.worker2.reference=worker.template
    worker.worker2.host=app02.btodomain.bto.org
    worker.worker2.port=8010

    # properties for loadbalancer
    worker.loadbalancer.type=lb
    worker.loadbalancer.balance_workers=worker1,worker2
```

Glassfish configuration I believed appropriate:

```
    create-jvm-options --target cluster01 "-DjvmRoute=\\${AJP_INSTANCE_NAME}"
    create-jvm-options --target cluster01 "-Dcom.sun.enterprise.web.connector.enableJK=\\${AJP_PORT}"
    create-system-properties --target instance0101 AJP_INSTANCE_NAME=instance0101
    create-system-properties --target instance0102 AJP_INSTANCE_NAME=instance0102
    create-system-properties --target instance0101 AJP_PORT=8009
    create-system-properties --target instance0102 AJP_PORT=8010
    create-network-listener --protocol http-listener-1 --listenerport “${AJP_PORT}” --jkenabled true --target cluster01 jk-connector
```

In addition to the configuration not working, when fiddling with the settings, I’ve twice ended up in a situation where test applications will not redeploy or un-deploy/deploy with Glassfish claiming that an application by the same name already existing (when it doesn’t)

Any help would be appreciated.

Mark

Answer (score 0):

Check your worker.list property. It only contains the load balancer but not the workers.

Answer (score 0):

Just change worker1 for the property "AJP_INSTANCE_NAME=instance0101" example:

properties for worker1

worker.instance0101.reference=worker.template worker.instance0101.host=app01.btodomain.bto.org worker.instance0101.port=8009

Do the same for all the workers and their respectives glassfish properties